Compute $\mathbb{E}\left[\tau^2\right]$ when $\tau=\inf\{t>0|W_t-W_0\geq +a\textrm{ or }W_t-W_0\leq -b\}$
Let $W$ be a Brownian motion, $a>0$ and $b>0$ real constants. Let $\tau$ be the stopping time
$$
\tau=\inf\left\{t\geq 0:W_t-W_0\geq +a\textrm{ or }W_t-W_0\leq -b\right\}
$$
I need to compute $\mathbb{E}[\tau^2]$.
My procedure.
As in this paper I consider the stopping time
$$
T(x) = \inf\left\{t\geq 0:W_t\geq +a\textrm{ or }W_t\leq -b| W_0=x\right\},
$$
with $-b<x<a$. Defining $M(x)\doteq\mathbb{E}[e^{-\alpha\,T(x)}]$ it must hold that
$$
\frac{1}{2}M^{\prime\prime}(x)=\alpha\,M(x),
$$
with boundary conditions $M(a)=M(-b)=1$ (if I am not wrong). The solution is (double-checked with software)
$$
M(x)=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x} \left(e^{\sqrt{2} a \sqrt{\alpha }}+e^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } b+2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } a+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } b}+1}.
$$
Now, to compute the expected value that I need I first compute
$$
\mathbb{E}[T(x)^2]=+\left.\frac{\partial^2M(x)}{\partial\alpha^2}\right|_{\alpha=0}=\frac{1}{3} (a-x) (b+x) \left(a^2+a (3 b+x)+b^2-b x-x^2\right),
$$
which, again, I double-checked with software. Whence
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau^2] = \mathbb{E}[T(0)^2] = \frac{1}{3} a b \left(a^2+3 a b+b^2\right)\quad(1).
$$
The problem is that when I check the formula $(1)$ with simulations it does not seem correct. So probably my procedure has some flaws. Any help is welcome.

As a check you could use the martingale $M_t=W_t^4-6tW_t^2+3t^2$.
To get $\Bbb E[\tau^2]$ out of this using optional stopping you'll need to compute $\Bbb E[\tau\mid  W_\tau =a]$ first.

I guess this is what I have to do: $\mathbb{E}[W_{\tau}^4-6,\tau,W_{\tau}^2+3,\tau]=0$ then compute $\mathbb{E}[\tau,W_{\tau}^2]$ using law of total expectation, which requires to know both $\mathbb{E}[\tau|W_{\tau}=a]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\tau|W_{\tau}=-b]$. For this purpose I can use, I guess, this reply of yours
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4905451
is this correct? Many thanks.

Looks like a plan!
